# How to remove encoder on wav file using ffmpeg?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

I have few wav files, which i am not be read using the wave module of python.
I get the following error:

wav = wave.open("filename.wav")
error:

"wave.Error: unknown format: %r"

I checked the encoding on the file using ffmpeg -i "filename.wav".
This is the output in metadata:
[image]

My question is
How do i remove this encoding from the wav file?
if you can point me in a direction
(i have already tried to find a decoder but was not successful)

Comment: That is the default encoder for WAV. This appears to be a limitation of your python module - with respect to either sampling rate, likely, or sample format.

Comment: Hi @Gyan, could you give me some idea on how to remove this encoding?
namely which decoder should i use or where would i find the information on which decoder to use?

Comment: You should consult the docs for the python wave module for accepted formats, then we can decide on next steps.